# Run application in client machine using SQL database from another PC

Tags: c#

I developed an application in C# and SQL and now I want to run it on another client machine without creating an installer.

I want to use the EXE from the Bin folder which is autogenerated when we run application in VS 2012. But it's not getting the SQL connection to the database on the other system.

Comment: look for information on database connections; you'll find plenty of answers here. the topic is too broad for a single question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

it should work as is, make sure that you have access to the database from the second machine (network and permissions).

Comment: I have enabled all the Remote Settings in SQL but non of pc getting access to server.

Comment: try to perform in the command line telnet to that SQL instance to make sure that the network is open.

Comment: no its not showing connectivity i have enabled everything, allowed all ports in firewall setting but still can not run app in other pc

Comment: If i will make setup file den will I able to run software in other pc?